# If cell is blank, what to do?

Tags: excel

I have line of code in excel and would like to add a function that If reference cell is empty, just return me empty. How am I able to add to that? Thanks in advance!

Here My code is so far:

```
=IF(
 ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R41: " & VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,10,FALSE))&"
 "&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R42: " & VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,10,FALSE))&"
 "&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R43: " & VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,10,FALSE))
```

Again, what if return cell got an empty string, how to add ISBLANK (or something else) in to the code?

Even I tried this and didn't work.

```
=IF(OR(
VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE)="",
VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE)="",
VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE)=""),"",
IF(
ISNA(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R41: " & VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE))&"
"&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R42: " & VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE))&"
"&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R43: " & VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE)))
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Nest the formula in:

```
=if(A2<>"",formula,"")
```

Comment: =IF(A2<>''
ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R41: " & VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,10,FALSE))&"
"&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R42: " & VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,10,FALSE))&"
"&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R43: " & VLOOKUP($A2,'[DataSheet.xlsx]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,10,FALSE))
,'') I tried this and didn't process it. maybe I am missing extra ()? Could you take a look again please? Thanks much!

Comment: @zzaewon  Use double-quotes instead of single-quotes in Formula, e.g., `=IF(A2<>"",__formula__,"")`.

Comment: @DavidZemens Please see above, I updated my agony with double-quotes with OR function. not a luck yet! :(

Comment: @zzaewon I'm in no position to evaluate your formula for accuracy. you might try breaking it into smaller chunks, and/or putting the formula manually in a cell to see where the syntax error may be...

Comment: @DavidZemens Sure, I'm keep working on troubleshooting. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: @zzaewon Sorry about the single quotes. Just to be clear, do you want to display a blank when A2 is blank? Or do you want to return a blank when the Vlookup formula returns a #N/A?

Comment: @NiteshHalai  Yes I do want to return a blank when A2 is blank, thanks for checking it out.

Comment: Embed a working formula (which returns the correct result when A2 is not blank) and insert that where I have kept "formula".